# JavaScript key undefined in IE over SSL

Tags: javascript, http, ssl, https, keycode

I'm working on a web app that works fine inside the LAN using HTTP but when I test it remotely over SSL it fails for IE (7 & 8). Firefox, Camino and Safari all work perfectly.

I've tracked down the issue to `key` being undefined. The relevant bit of code is:

```
function showResult(e,str,num) {
    var key = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

    if(((key > 32 && key < 58) || (key > 64 && key < 91) || (key > 95 && key < 123)) && (str.length >= num)) {
```

Any clues as to why `key` would be undefined for IE over SSL but works fine over HTTP? Better yet, can someone tell me how to overcome this problem? FWIW, I don't need to support IE prior to version 7.

**Update:**

There was an answer which suggested replacing

```
var key = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
```

with

```
var key;
e = e || window.event;
key = e.keyCode || e.which;
```

That works. The problem now is that I can't accept that answer because it has been deleted.

Comment: What does `console.log(window.Event)` contain?

Comment: Are you certain that you're passing the event object into this function? Assert `e == window.event` in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll re-add that answer, even though it wasn't mine, and add some info along the way so you can feel OK with accepting it even if it wasn't my answer from the beginning.

So, the suggested code is this:

```
var key;
e = e || window.event;
key = e.keyCode || e.which;
```

What does `||` do? For one it's the logical or operator, which would return true if one of the sides evaluate to boolean true.

It also has another use in JS. If you give it two arguments and the first one is undefined, it will return the second argument. This means, in the code above, that if `e` is undefined, you instead get `window.event` which is IE's traditional event object.

Same thing goes with `e.keyCode || e.which` whichever one exists is used. So in the end, you're likely to end up with a valid key code on various browsers. All is good in wonderland.

**But wait, doesn't your original code do something similar?**

```
var key = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
```

Uh-huh. What's that? JavaScript is case-sensisitive, so `window.Event` is **not** the same as  `window.event` in the code above. `window.event` is IE's traditional event object that you would use get information about the event that occurred, while `window.Event` (which you can see from the initial capital letter) is a constructor, or more specifically in this case [an interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event).

Point is, in that code it was used to detect Mozilla. If it exists, choose `e.which` (One of the places where Mozilla stores the key code) otherwise go for `e.keyCode` where IE would store the key code.

However, this is based on the flawed assumption that IE doesn't have the `window.Event` constructor defined. It does have it defined as of IE8, at least. This means that `e.which` is chosen over `e.keyCode`, on newer versions of IE. `e.which` has never and will never be supported in IE. That's why `key` ends up being undefined.

**But, uhm, why does it differ between encrypted and unencrypted connections?** That's a good question. While I cannot know for sure without access to your development environment, I would assume it has something with IE's compatibility modes.

IE has historically (over the last 10 years) been the most quirky and non-standard browser around. This has lead to people a) programming ignorantly according to IE's standards b) creating workarounds for IE's behaviors. If MS just made IE standards-compliant, that would break many pages which rely on IE's quirky behavior in one way or the other. Microsoft has ackowledged this by making IE8+ emulate older versions of IE so pages won't break, unless told otherwise.

I can only assume that, for whatever reason, in your test environment the page ends up running in the "IE7" mode which might not have the `window.Event` constructor/interface defined. This would make your old code use `e.keyCode` which is ey OK. Then perhaps in your production environment, or maybe just because of the encrypted connection (only ghawd knows what MS is doing) you end up with a newer IE mode so `window.Event` is actually defined and `e.which` is chosen. This makes IE a cheeky monkey.

Bottom line: Use the new code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation. Although I normally code in C and am therefore used to dealing with case sensitivity I'm new to JavaScript and much of what I have is copy and paste. In fact `var key = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;` was copied from another answer here on SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you've included a script over http (rather than https), which will fail to load because the page itself is secure and the included file insecure.

Comment: All includes are referenced by relative path only. I've also been able to get everything to work by temporarily replacing the test line with `if(str.length >= num) {`. Of course then it no longer filters out unwanted keys.